# Is "human resources" men?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

> We help you verify, validate and monitor your 
>   systems live, 24/7, with our human resources who are rich in experience, commitment, dedication, flexibility and with high analytical skills...

Could you help me check if the words I used in this statement make sense?  Is *human resources* a thingie noun that I should use *which* with instead of *who*?

Comment: I'll do it!  Pick me!  United States Dollars or Euros will be fine.

Comment: If human resources means people not HR, just say people.

Comment: It looks like its supposed to mean "resources who happen to be human, as opposed to technological", not the management of people.

Comment: In the corporate world, anyone willing to work for the corporation is just a chunk of _meat with benefits_, no different from raw coconuts, silicon, iron ore, and fork lifts. They used to be _people_ until corporations decided to replace them with robots and cheaper foreign workers; then they were transmogrified into _human resources_ and sold down the river. [No political comment intended here and not a troll -- I don't want a discussion, just a snicker or two; just an explanation in the same register as the term "human resources".]

Comment: Thank you, I am going to change it into 
"our people" instead

Comment: Seems to me that whoever down-voted the question might want to reconsider. The comments had a positive effect on the OP, who now will change his language because of what a few responders said. I think that makes everyone's effort worthwhile.

Comment: @Huizhe  I think you are being very generous.  I did not think expressions like 'thingie noun' were permitted.  Also this question could have been answered by simply looking up 'Human Resources'.  What people have actually done is to use the question as a platform to air their political opinions.  But you are right, this is an example of a question being answered in a helpful way.  By the way, what is an 'OP' - OK (Original Poster).

Comment: Yes, an original poster. Why should we be emotional monsters here?

Comment: @Huizhe: The fact that everyone's efforts have been made worthwhile is indeed a good thing, but that's not the only factor to be considered when upvoting or downvoting a quesiton. I could ask a question here about my math homework, or about what to name my baby, and the latter wouldn't become a better question just because I decided to christen my child with one of the suggested names. P.S. Now a downvote makes one a "monster"?

Comment: @J.R. No, I wasn't suggesting that a downvote makes one a monster. Robin Michael said I was "very generous". I disagree. I just turned "miserly", the opposite of "generous", into "monster". I'm reading _Silas Marner_. The citizens of Marner's home village and of Raveloe turned him into a miser and, in their minds, a monster. I'm prone to hyperbole as well as to parallel construction, and more than a little obsessive-compulsive, which often makes my opinions unpleasantly trenchant and tendentious. But this was a good English question, IMHO. I used to be a teacher; I'm not a cop.

Comment: Suggestion: "with our skilled analysts who are rich in experience, commitment, dedication, flexibility...". I hate the term *resources* to mean *people*.

Comment: @Huizhe: Thanks for that clarification. I'll try to remember that "trenchant and tendentious" reference in the future; so long as I filter your comments through those glasses, I'm confident I'll enjoy them. :^)

Comment: Bad use of the phrase 'human resources' - in the corporate world it is what used to be called a 'personnel department' and is rarely used to mean employees. I've often heard project managers refer to people (software developers in my case) as 'resource' (singular) but nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

*Is human resources a thingie noun that I should use **which** with instead of **who**?*

Yes, it's an "inanimate object" that refers to a certain kind of asset of an organization. It of course, consists of animate human beings, which is only incidental to the context.

So, if you would at all use *human resources*, then you will need to say *which*.

One way would be to make it more reader-friendly by rephrasing as

*... with our human resources **bringing in** rich experience, ...*

Comment: Human Resources are not an 'inanimate object' therefore it should be 'who'.

Comment: Dear Kris, You have got 8,367 points and yet you have clearly got this answer wrong.  I think that where the confusion lies is that Human Resources (capital letters) is the name of a department within an organisation.  This department used to be called the Personnel Department.  Actually, this incident makes me think about my motivation.  What is it? - a desire to help, power/authority, a mental exercise - I am not sure.  The other thing is, I know I am right, but how can I convince you?

Comment: @RobinMichael Very nice, thank you. "I know I am right, but how can I convince you?" -- which is what ELU is all about: find canonical answers. You can see that no one has said "I know I am right" on this site -- we don't do that here.

Answer (score 2):

> We help you verify, validate and monitor your systems live, 24/7, with our human resources who are rich in experience, commitment, dedication, flexibility and with high analytical skills...

There is nothing wrong with this statement.  You could replace the words 'human resources' with the word 'people' or 'staff'.

> > We help you verify, validate and monitor your systems live, 24/7, with our people who are rich in experience, commitment, dedication, flexibility and with high analytical skills...

When Bob Diamond, the Head of Barclays Bank was being questioned by a Parliamentary Select Committee, he constantly referred to 'the people at Barclays'.

Another word you could replace 'human resources' with is 'personnel'.

Both Human Relations and Personnel can be proper nouns and can be capitalised.  Although of course the meaning changes somewhat.

It is 'who' not 'which' as you are referring to people.

Comment: For most part, the answer does not discuss the basic question of *who* vs *which*. When it eventually does, what the answer says seems incorrect: *human resources* would go with *which*, not *who* -- see other answers. I've not yet down voted.

Comment: Human Resources are not an 'inanimate object' therefore it should be 'who'.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of your political opinion, the use of the phrase *human resources* here is bad, and OP puts his finger on the reason: *human resources* are neither men nor women but economic units.

In a context where you're trying to assure your readers that their inquiries will be answered by **real human beings**, rich in **real human qualities**, it is imbecilically counterproductive to employ language which reduces those human beings to components of economic analysis—to designate them by what OP eloquently identifies as a "thingie noun" which (as OP recognizes) calls for the impersonal *which* rather than *who*.

Comment: I think that this is an opinion about large organisations and capitalism in general.  Where men and women are units of production - inanimate objects.  Again, it is interesting that someone with 2,097 points should get this wrong.

Comment: @RobinMichael, you're missing the point: not that it's a bad attitude but that it's **bad ad copy**. The language is inappropriate because it contradicts the message. "People", as in the example you cite from Barclay's, would be far better.

Comment: I could be generous and give you a point but I don't feel in the mood.